# Do toxic backlinks really influece your DA for Google since it is a 3rd party metric?

Tags: seo

My question to the SEO guru's on Stackoverflow is as the title says:

Do toxic backlinks really influece your DA for Google since it is a 3rd party metric?

I started a new website and bought some backlinks. Unfortunately most of them are seen as "toxic" by Semrush.The SEO dude whom I bought it from said to me:

> DA, PA, Toxicity and so on are all 3rd-party metrics and Google does not care about them. These links are fine and will increase your website at Google.

For all my other websites, I always disavowed any link that was even remotely toxic. But now it made me wonder... is the guy right and honest?

I mean... some URL'S look like this:

> https://juliusdulzp.kylieblog.com/23111942/some-title-comes-here

I mean, to me personally that looks wonky and I would have disavowed that link.

I hope you guys (and girls) can share your experience with me and explain to me, once and for all, if I should ignore 3rd party metrics.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely unrelated backlinks are toxic. I have seen a client ignoring this advice and their site tanking as a direct result of purchasing backlinks - and the blackhat/scammer that sold them to you should - and likely does know better.

He is arguably partially right that DA and PA are at least somewaht outdated metrics, but toxicity is a big one that Google stresses.    Google promotes the idea of E-E-A-T (which supercedes E-A-T).  This stands for Expertise, experience, Authorativeness and Trustworthiness - Trustworthiness.

Don't believe me.  Believe Google - https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/guidelines.raterhub.com/en//searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The guy you got the site from is using information that is very, very, old. Google is adept at determining paid links ... US Patent 6,799,176; US Patent 6,285,999; US Patent 8,719,276; US Patent 7,783,639 ...

> A system includes a ranking component that ranks nodes, such as web
> sites, to obtain ranking values that define a quality judgment of the
> nodes. The ranking values are based on links between the nodes and,
> among other things, deemphasize links between affiliated nodes.
> Additionally, the amount of rank that any particular node can
> contribute to another node may be capped at a threshold level, thus
> tending to prevent some nodes from unduly influencing the ranking
> values.

Beyond the "de-emphasizing," of those links, they also dilute the theme of the page/site. The link farms don't have any type of good information or authority on the subject matter that your site is about -- They are not your peers. The farms are about random topics and some of their links may be to low-quality content.

I would tend towards disavowing any link that SEMrush says is toxic, and I'm generally one of those people who ignore links from questionable sources.